# splitting a string with multiple delimiters doesn't work

Tags: python, string, split, delimiter

I'm trying to split a string suing multiple delimiters. Somehow it just doesn't work, it only works if I use each delimiter separately. What am I doing wrong?

```
string = '\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nfirst_col: col1 \r\n\r\nsecond_col: col2 \r\n\r\nthird_col: col3 \r\n\r\nfourth_col: col4 \r\n\r\nfith_col: col5\r\n'
splitter = "\r\n\r\n | \r\n\r\n| "
string.split(splitter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to split the string according to a regex pattern:

```
import re

string = '\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nfirst_col: col1 \r\n\r\nsecond_col: col2 \r\n\r\nthird_col: col3 \r\n\r\nfourth_col: col4 \r\n\r\nfith_col: col5\r\n'
splitter = "\r\n\r\n | \r\n\r\n| "

new_string = re.split(splitter, string)
```